# Eclipse for C++ not recognizing brewed GSL and Boost libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, boost, gsl

I am on a system running Mac OS X. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.2 for C/C++, in my case C++. I am attempting to create a project that uses the GSL and Boost libraries. However, Eclipse appears to not be able to locate the GSL library and appears to recognize the Boost library, but doesn't appear to be able to do anything included in the Boost library. Both libraries were installed using Homebrew. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl.h>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int x = 5;
    gsl::owner<int*> p = &x;
    boost::optional<string>;
    return 0;
}
```

The errors are as follows:

1. With the line `#include <gsl.h>`, it shows `fatal error: 'gsl.h' file not found`.
2. With the line `gsl::owner<int*> p = &x;` it shows `Symbol 'owner' could not be resolved`.
3. With the line `boost::optional<string>;` it shows `Type 'boost::optional<string>' could not be resolved`. This one is weird because it appears to have no issues with the `boost/optional.hpp` file.

This other information would probably be helpful:

I am using the MacOS X toolchain. Should I switch to the Cross GCC toolchain?

Here are the library search paths listed under the project preferences > C/C++ Build > Settings > MacOS X C++ Linker > Libraries: `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0/include` and `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/include`.

I am following Trevor Payne's Let's Learn C++ tutorial series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've pointed the libraries, not the includes, at the header files.

Right click the protect in the Project Explorer. Select properties from the pop-up menu. Navigate in the Properties dialogue C/C++ General->Paths And Symbols. Select the Includes tab. Add /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0/include and /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/include to the C++ Language for all Configurations.

Remove the include directories from the Libraries tab and then head to the Library Paths tab to add the locations of the libraries, if you need any. Boost is often header only. GSL I don't know from Atom.

Comment: This worked, however another main issue was that I was using `#include <gsl.h>` instead of `#include <gsl_sf.h>`. I don't know what the difference is between those though.

Answer (score 1):

Great job identifying the right issues and providing good debugging information.

Since you *have* installed GSL and Boost with Homebrew, they are probably installed correctly and the compiler just can't find the correct header and library files -- And this is probably because you're using the incorrect paths in the wrong setting.

In the `Linker > Libraries` options, you're using the two `include` paths for Boost and GSL. These belong in a different path option for finding headers, not libraries (I'm not sure where it is exactly, I don't have a mac!). Make sure you're following the tutorial's instructions carefully here.

You *do* also need to put library paths in the Library options, however: e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/include` should be something like `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/lib`